# Is it possible to exclude a file from the content root in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to exclude individual `.java` files from a Content Root in IntelliJ. The [documentation on "Excluding Files from Project"](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/excluding-files-from-project.html) suggests that this is not possible (it explicitly says **This action is not applicable to Java files and binaries.**)

Being incredulous to such a limitation, I have tried editing my `.iml` file, optimistically inserting XML elements such as `<excludeFile>` under the `<content>` element, but nothing seems to take.

Does anyone know a way to do this (documented or otherwise)? Or have any clue why this feature is not supported? By comparison, Eclipse allows for an arbitrary `including` pattern for a `<classpathentry>` element in its `.classpath` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [exclude files from compilation and classpath](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/compiler-excludes.html). As far as I understand it will have the same effect as manipulating with `<classpathentry>` in Eclipse.

To exclude files/folders by pattern and globally use **Ignore files and folders** option in the [File Types](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-types.html) dialog. This way the files will be completely ignored and not visible in the Project View, but it's probably not what you want.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, no, I do not think that is what I want. I want to exclude a .java file from one module, but still include it in another module. What you are talking about would exclude it from the project altogether, correct?

Comment: If you have a single file that you want to be available in the classpath of one module, but not in the classpath of another module (which depends on the first module), it will not work. If you have 2 copies of a file in different modules, you can exclude it from one of them in the compiler settings.

Comment: OK, yes, that is what I want to do, though it is unfortunate that it will not work.

If I looked into submitting a patch to IntelliJ that would change this, (1) do you have any idea how difficult it would be, and (2) would you accept it?

Comment: I'd start with a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA describing the use case and why such feature would be needed in a real world projects. If JetBrains finds it useful, the feature will be implemented eventually or your patch attached to the issue will be accepted.